# Positioning buttons one to the right and two just to the side (left) but vertically stacked in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have searched for a couple of hours to find a solution for my problem but have failed in doing so. The problem i am having is the vertical stacking of the two buttons.

This is what i am trying to do: Where it says button here twice is where I am trying to put my buttons but all I can do is have them lined horizontally and not vertically.

Big button Smallbutton

```
        Smallbutton
```

CODE:

```
<button type="button" style="clear: right; display: inline-block; " onclick="playbr()">           <img src="Images/Queen.png"/></button>
<!---Button Here vertically---> 
<!---Button Here vertically--->
```

So one to the far left and the other two stacked vertically just to the side of the big.

Comment: Did you try adding `<br />` between the buttons..?

Comment: Yah, i did try that but all it does is put one button below the image button and small button. And not under the first small button and to the right of the image button.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2" valign="top">Big Button</td>
     <td>Small Button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Small Button</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I believe your best bet would be to place everything in a `table`. This will help you align everything the way you want. It would look something like this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYqy5/1/)

You can play around with the height and width to create the alignment you need.